# Excel VBA calculate height of row

Tags: vba, excel

I have several rows in a workbook that I am working on that require both merged columns, and merged rows.  For this reason, Excel’s auto fit does me no good.  It is also possible, and probable, that at some point these will need to expand beyond Excel’s 409.5pt limit for row height.

For this reason, I am looking for a way to calculate the total necessary height of a set of rows so they will fit a block of text properly using VBA.

How can I calculate the necessary row height to fit a block of text, knowing that it will exceed 409.5pt?  The font size and cell width will be constant, so that can be used to calculate it necessary.

Comment: A few questions. Why not just wrap the text since you are fixing the width? Also what do you plan on doing if your block exceeds the maximum height?

Comment: The text is wrapped, that is what causes it to exceed the height.  If it does exceed the height, I can take the calculated height, say 1000pt, and create 3 rows, 2@409pt, and 1@182pt, then merge them, all dynamically with VBA.  This will then show the full text.

Comment: Why use *cells* when a *shape* (like a TextBox) would seem to solve all of these problems, including the limitation on row height.

Comment: @DavidZemens Is there a way to auto size a text box, while keeping it from overlapping or covering the text/formulas/data below it in the sheet?

Comment: @engineersmnky Forgot to tag you yesterday.  See above.

Comment: @Butters if you have conditions, then you can't auto-size, you need to define some criteria/logic by which the shape will be sized. Yes, it can be done, but it can't be done with the native "Auto-size shape to fit text" option.

Comment: @DavidZemens  Thanks, I'm working on a solution now that autosizes the text box, and then sizes the cells around it to match.

Answer (score -1):

12pt font is like 1/6", i.e., there are 72 points in an inch.  using your font size, you should be able to come up with an algorithm that reasonably approximates the necessary row height.

Use something like this to print a list of font sizes & row heights, and use the results to come up with your conversion formula.

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Range
Dim i as Integer

Set r = [a1]
r.EntireRow.AutoFit = True
For i = 1 to 10

    MsgBox "Row height = " & r.Height & vbCrLF & _
            "Font size = " & r.Font.Size

    Debug.Print r.Height & vbTab & r.Font.Size

    r.Font.Size = r.Font.Size + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Width is trickier since individual characters have different widths (`i` is much narrower than `W` in many fonts), although there are some functions out there which will calculate the width of *each individual character* for common fonts.

Comment: @z̫͋  "Point" is a unit of measurement used in typography that is equal to 1/72 inch. It is used primarily for representing the height of characters and the amount of space between lines, also known as leading.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/76388

Comment: @z̫͋ David Zemens is correct "Point" is different than "Pixel"